# Private field 'showGuess' never assigned

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I already initialize and created a listener for the button showGuess. the app crashes btw

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button showGuess;

public MainActivity(Button showGuess) {
    this.showGuess = showGuess;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showGuess.findViewById(R.id.button_name);

    showGuess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowGuess.class); 
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the error/warning written in debug section:

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.Button.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a little edit :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button showGuess;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showGuess=findViewById(R.id.button_name);

    showGuess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowGuess.class); 
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```